# Laravel Forge queue workers

Tags: sockets, laravel, redis, queue, web-worker

I deployed with Forge and set up a worker to handle Redis queues.

Every email is queued in my app and if I try to send an email in the "support" page, it works.

Nonetheless if I try to register an account, the whole process works but the activation email is not sent.

[This is my log](http://laravel.io/bin/QN9L1), it seems it can't connect to mysql to store the failed job (even if DB connection works, since my registered account is stored properly) but it doesn't provide info about the job failure.

Also, both my testing and local environments can send the activation email. What's wrong?

Comment: You'll need to post some code of how you are queuing your mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by restarting the queue worker.